# Почему os.environ.get возвращает None

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Api Telegram Bot ошибка с апи ботом. При попытке перед кодом вывести API командой

```
print(os.environ.get('1234567890:AAFlQ72anCD5R36ZTY0ZE8Ma03tZOfi4ngE'))
```

В консоль выводится "None" Что делать?

Comment: Дело в том, что с помощью функции `os.environ.get` вы получаете переменные окружения. Переменная с использованным вами именем не задана, и, соответственно, выводится None. Пожалуйста, опишите желаемое поведение

Comment: В параметре os.environ.get() нужно указать имя переменной окружения, в которую вы записали ваш токен. А вы вместо этого передаете туда сам токен. Переменной окружения с именем как у вашего токена нет, поэтому получаете None.